# Working with numbers in forms

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm building an app with Aurelia and really liking the framework so far, but I've stumbled upon an issue where I'm trying to display a list of checkboxes whose values are numbers (ID:s in reality) and Aurelia seems to convert them to strings and thus comparison fails.

I basically have something like:

```js
export class MyVm {
    constructor () {
        this.items = [
            {name: 'Foo', id: 0},
            {name: 'Bar', id: 1},
            {name: 'Baz', id: 2}
        ];
        this.selectedItems = [0, 2];
    }
}
```

And in my view:

```html
<ul>
    <li repeat.for="item of items">
        <input type="checkbox" value.bind="item.id" checked.bind="selectedItems">
        ${item.name}
    </li>
</ul>
```

For this to work I actually have to do `this.selectedItems = ["0", "2"]` which just leads to a bunch of other comparison problems in my own code. I also don't want to send the selected item as a string to the server later on when saving the data.

I've tried using a simple value converter that converts toString toView and parseInt fromView, but I can't run this converter on the array of selectedItems:

```js
export class IntValueConverter {
    toView (val) {
        return val.toString();
    }

    fromView (val) {
        return parseInt(val);
    }
}
```

How would you go about solving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost have it. There's one small problem with this part:

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="${item.id}" checked.bind="selectedItems">
```

The `<input>` element's `value` attribute coerces everything it's assigned to a string.  Not only that, a string interpolation binding (eg `${...}`) also coerces everything to a string.  You need to preserve the numeric item id.  Replace `value="${item.id}"` with `model.bind="item.id"` and it will work.  No need for a converter.

Coincidentally I [just pushed](https://github.com/aurelia/binding/commit/0719de3e3e45e51eaf935fe68b232808d7f61caf) a set of exhaustive docs on checkbox, radio and select binding to the Aurelia binding repo. They haven't been published to the official Aurelia docs app yet but they should be there on Tuesday.

Also- if you see anything weird with items whose id is zero- there's [a fix](https://github.com/aurelia/binding/commit/9d39a1adee1175e44d20634593a297ba5cdc674a) going out on Tuesday for that as well.

Finally, I know this is not your question, but for others that land here looking for binding numbers in forms, here's a couple basic examples using a custom element and custom attribute:

https://gist.run/?id=d9d8dd9df7be2dd2f59077bad3bfb399

Comment: Oh man thank you so much! Can you explain why I need to use `model.bind` as opposed to `value.bind` though? I really liked Aurelia for its simplicity, basically just adding `.bind` to any attribute you want to bind to, this feels a little more Angular to me :/ Btw: The `value="${item.id}"` was actually a "typo" (I was using `value.bind` in my code)

Comment: The html input element's value attribute coerces everything to a string so we have to store it somewhere else to preserve the real value

Comment: Alright :) I've now changed all my `value.bind`:s to `model.bind`:s and it works like a charm. However, I also changed it on an `input[type=range]` which completely stopped working. Do you know why it doesn't work the same for all inputs? Is it because range already is numeric?

Comment: It's only for checkbox inputs, radio inputs and option elements